# How do I eliminate spam sigup on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, spam, buddypress

I have a wordpress / Buddypress site.... And am having serious issues with spam users signup.... 
Have tried using Akismet, but it is seemingly not helping matters.

Please who has a idea as to which plugin to use or if anyone has an idea on which other method to use, please share

Comment: Try this nice plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wangguard/

Comment: a simple but quite effective change you could make as part of your overall strategy is to change your register page's slug to something different. Sometimes spam bots look for `/register/` so using something like `/sign-me-up/` will make your site _stealth_ to at least some of the bots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a form for users to register you can use a captcha like in all forms, e.g. I use really simple captcha in combination with contact form 7.

Answer (score 0):

Using either captcha on your forms and/or a plugin can be useful.

Many of the forms wordpress plugins come with have captcha built in - or it can be added. Google also provides reCaptcha, and doing an internet search will bring up plenty of information on both.

Two plugins I've used in the past which I've found to work well are [WangGuard](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wangguard/) and [WordFence](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/)

Wangguard mainly as `WangGuard cleans your database from sploggers, spam users and unwanted users.`

Wordfence is good as it can `Block entire malicious networks. Includes advanced IP and Domain WHOIS to report malicious IP's or networks and block entire networks using the firewall. Report security threats to network owner.`

Ultimately remember **people will always have their own opinions on security** - but there are plenty of ways to improve your wordpress / buddypress security. Wordpress also has information on [Hardening Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) against malicious attacks